# SPI Read Function of STM8S

Tags: arduino, rf, spi, stm8

I am converting arduino-nrf905 library for stm8s. There is one spi function on the arduino library, it is SPI.Transfer(uint8_t reg). This function can write and read spi. But, there is two function on the stm8s peripharel library. This functions are SPI_SendData(uint8_t reg) and SPI_ReceiveData(void).

SPI.transfer code of arduino library:

```
byte SPIClass::transfer(byte _data) {
  SPDR = _data;
  while (!(SPSR & _BV(SPIF)))
    ;
  return SPDR;
}
```

SPI_SendData of STM8S library:

```
void SPI_SendData(uint8_t Data)
{
  SPI->DR = Data; /* Write in the DR register the data to be sent*/
}
```

SPI_ReceiveData of stm8s

```
uint8_t SPI_ReceiveData(void)
{
  return ((uint8_t)SPI->DR); /* Return the data in the DR register*/
}
```

I want to convert this code to stm8s, but it does not work.

Arduino Code:

```
((uint8_t*)data)[i] = spi_transfer(NRF905_CMD_NOP);
```

STM8S Code:

```
SPI_SendData(NRF905_CMD_NOP);
((uint8_t*)data)[i] = SPI_ReceiveData();
```

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean with 'doesn't work'?

Answer (score 1):

There are flags that you must wait on, flags that will indicate when SPI transmission is done or a byte has been received. Try this:

```
while (SPI_GetFlagStatus(SPI_FLAG_TXE) == RESET); // wait for any previous data to be sent; checks if the Transmit Register is empty
SPI_SendData(NRF905_CMD_NOP);
while (SPI_GetFlagStatus(SPI_FLAG_RXNE) == RESET);  // wait for a byte to come in; checks if the Receive register is not empty
((uint8_t*)data)[i] = SPI_ReceiveData();
```